# Can/Should Spring AOP be used with Microservices & Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop, microservices

We are analyzing different concepts for one of my projects. We decided to use `Spring Boot` & `Microservices` architecture.

After further discussions, we came to a query whether we **CAN/SHOULD** use `Spring AOP` to resolve cross cutting concerns of various `microservices`?

If **not** how can we address common concerns of microservices like logging, transaction mgmt, etc?

I have googled this topic extensively (even went to 5 pages for same search), but no luck. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Logging & transaction management are common in all the services and I think they would be in most of the services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spring interceptors.  They have interceptors and factories for just about anything.  Lets you add instrumentation and common code to all aspects.

UPDATE:  samples interceptors and factories.

[ClientHttpRequestInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html)
[FilterRegistrationBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html)
[SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html)
[ChannelInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/support/ChannelInterceptor.html)

Comment: If I have three spring boot projects as microservices, is there a way to use spring AOP for common concerns in these independent projects?

Comment: No need to use AOP directly.  Use the interceptors and factories instead.  For example we create a common jar that injects factories and interceptors into our projects.  No need for AOP.

Comment: Lets say you have a requirement to do some security check on all incoming HTTP requests.  Then you can use the FilterRegistrationBean to add a Servlet Filter that will do this security check.  Write a new JAR that has your Servlet Filter implementation and uses the FilterRegistrationBean to add the Filter to your project.  Now your Filter will get called on every inbound HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is anything to worry about using AOP. This is how Spring does things usually under the hood.

I'd just be careful with logging method invocations, especially parameters which is the common use (abuse) of AOP.

Ususally the less code you write the better. If you can use standard, proven way of doing things - use it.

Comment: If I have three spring boot projects as microservices, is there a way to use spring AOP for common concerns in these independent projects?

Comment: Most of the common concerns Spring Boot will handle itself. Or you'll use a library like Javamelody. Of course you can always create a library nd share it. However it seems that you're focusing on a technology too much rathr than on a problem to solve. AOP is just a tool like StringUtils. First thing about what you're trying to solve.